# Download pre-trained BERT model locally

Tags: python-3.x, word-embedding

I am using the SentenceTransformers library (here: https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/#pretrained-models) for creating embeddings of sentences using the pretrained model `bert-base-nli-mean-tokens`. I have an application that will be deployed to a device that does not have internet access. How can I save this model locally so that when I call it, it loads the model locally, rather than attempting to download from the internet? As the library maintainers make clear, the method `SentenceTransformer` downloads the model from the internet (see here: https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/#pretrained-models) and I cannot find a method for saving the model locally.

Comment: I'm trying out the same thing. Were you able to identify it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Hugging face usage](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-max-tokens?text=Paris%20is%20the%20%5BMASK%5D%20of%20France.)

You can download the models locally by using the Hugging Face transformer library method.

```
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens")
tokenizer.save_pretrained('./local_directory/')
model.save_pretrained('./local_directory/')
```

Comment: Hey, The generated config.json doesn't have a version. So I'm getting a `KeyError: '__version__'`

Comment: @LazyCoder How did you resolved this issue (KeyError: '__version__')?

Answer (score 5):

After instantiating the SentenceTransformer via download, you can then save it to any path of your choosing with the 'save()' method.

```
model = SentenceTransformer('distilbert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
model.save('/my/local/directory/for/models/')
```

The accepted answer doesn't work, as it doesn't have the encapsulating folder and config.json that SentenceTransformer is looking for