# Download pre-trained sentence-transformers model locally

Tags: word-embedding, bert-language-model, huggingface-tokenizers, sentence-transformers

I am using the SentenceTransformers library (here: https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/#pretrained-models) for creating embeddings of sentences using the pre-trained model bert-base-nli-mean-tokens. I have an application that will be deployed to a device that does not have internet access. Here, it's already been answered, how to save the model [Download pre-trained BERT model locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002081/download-pre-trained-bert-model-locally). Yet I'm stuck at loading the saved model from the locally saved path.

When I try to save the model using the above-mentioned technique, these are the output files:

```
('/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens/tokenizer_config.json',
 '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens/special_tokens_map.json',
 '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens/vocab.txt',
 '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens/added_tokens.json')
```

When I try to load it in the memory, using

```
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(to_save_path)
```

I'm getting

```
Can't load config for '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens'. Make sure that:

- '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens' is a correct model identifier listed on 'https://huggingface.co/models'

- or '/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens' is the correct path to a directory containing a config.json
```

Comment: Hey were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: yes, it's solved

Comment: can you update the solution please

Answer (score 29):

You can download and load the model like this

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
modelPath = "local/path/to/model

model = SentenceTransformer('bert-base-nli-stsb-mean-tokens')
model.save(modelPath)
model = SentenceTransformer(modelPath)
```

this worked for me.You can check the SBERT documentation for model details for the SentenceTransformer class [Here][1]

[1]: [https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/SentenceTransformer.html#:~:text=class,Optional%5Bstr%5D%20%3D%20None](https://www.sbert.net/docs/package_reference/SentenceTransformer.html#:%7E:text=class,Optional%5Bstr%5D%20%3D%20None))

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to solve this issue:

- Assuming you have trained your BERT base model locally (colab/notebook), in order to use it with the [Huggingface AutoClass](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/auto.html), then the model (along with the tokenizers,vocab.txt,configs,special tokens and tf/pytorch weights) has to be uploaded to Huggingface. The steps to do this is mentioned [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_sharing.html). Once it is uploaded, there will be a repository created with your username, and then the model can be accessed as follows:

```py
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
from transformers import pipeline

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("<username>/<model-name>")
```

- The second way is to use the trained model locally, and this can be done by using [pipelines](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/pipelines.html).The following is an example how to use this model trained(&saved) locally for your use-case (giving an example from my locally trained QA model):

```py
from transformers import AutoModelForQuestionAnswering,AutoTokenizer,pipeline
nlp_QA=pipeline('question-answering',model='./abhilash1910/distilbert-squadv1',tokenizer='./abhilash1910/distilbert-squadv1')
QA_inp={
    'question': 'What is the fund price of Huggingface in NYSE?',
    'context': 'Huggingface Co. has a total fund price of $19.6 million dollars'
}
result=nlp_QA(QA_inp)
result
```

- The third way is to directly use [Sentence Transformers](https://huggingface.co/sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens) from the Huggingface models repo.

There are also other ways to resolve this but these might help. Also this list of pretrained models might [help](https://huggingface.co/transformers/pretrained_models.html).

Comment: I wish to use pre-trained bert-base-nli-mean-tokens model. 
The third option is not feasible as I don't have internet access to my local system. I should be able to save it once(downloading from the internet)and onwards, it should be loaded from the system without having any internet access. 
from transformers import AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("sentence-transformers/bert-base-nli-mean-tokens")
tokenizer.save_pretrained(local_path)
loaded_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(local_path)
When I load the model, I get above mentioned error

Comment: I don't understand why everyone just assumes `BERT` and `sentence-transformers` are the same thing ?